# Como hacer una funcion que rote el div

Tags: javascript

estoy varado en un un código con javascript. el código consiste en hacer click en un elemento div y este debe rotar 90grados por cada click hasta llegar a 360grados. yo todavía no encuentro como hacer una función que pueda ejecutar esto.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>myPage</title>
    <style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}


.contenedor{width:100%;height:100vh;border:2px solid brown; display:flex; justify-content:center;align-items:center}


.rolover{width:40%;height:30%;border:2px solid navy;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="rolover" id="rol">
    <p>rolover</p>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
<script>
Myfunction=()=>{


x.style.transform="rotate(90deg)";
}

let x=document.getElementById("rol");


x.addEventListener("click",Myfunction);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

con esta función se puede rotar 90 grados con cada click hasta los 90.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>myPage</title>
        <style>
          * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          }

          .contenedor {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            border: 2px solid brown;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }

          .rolover {
            width: 40%;
            height: 30%;
            border: 2px solid navy;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="rolover" id="rol">
            <p>rolover</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script>
        let rotation = 0;
        Myfunction = () => {
          if (rotation >= 360) return;
          rotation += 90;
          x.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
        };

        let x = document.getElementById('rol');

        x.addEventListener('click', Myfunction);
      </script>
    </html>
```